# ExtJS textfield mask

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a grid that has a textfield on it. I would like to apply a mask to the textfield so that when the users type in there data it automatically ensures the formatting is good as well as the property deliminators. Coming from .NET it's a simple property to set but it seems from the searching I am doing it's much more complicated in ExtJS. Here is a sample of the data I would like to create a mask for  00-00-00-00-00-00. Each two digit block can be either numeric or ASCII.

Comment: Does the maskRe config help? http://ext5-docs.site/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-maskRe

Comment: #colinramsay from what I read it appears that that property only allows for validating the input via regular expression not actually creating the look and feel. Here is a sample example I found online: http://www.dotnetperls.com/maskedtextbox.png

Comment: True. I think what you'd have to do is create a custom field class and use maskRe in combination with capturing the keypress event on the underlying element, manipulating current value, then manually calling setValue on the textfield...

Answer (score 1):

I just found this project which might give you a starting point:

https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ux.form.field.Phone

The class itself accepts a `tpl` which you could likely customise for your needs:

https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ux.form.field.Phone/blob/master/packages/Ux.form.field.Phone/src/form/field/Phone.js